# mysqld looks for config file and data in wrong place

Tags: windows, windows-8, mysql

I have new MySQL portable located in

```
D:\Apps\MySQL\mysql-5.7.13-winx64
```

and it has `my.ini` file in

```
D:\Apps\MySQL\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\my.ini
```

The content of `ini` file is follows:

```
[client]
port=3306

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 

port=3306
basedir="D:/Apps/MySQL/mysql-5.7.13-winx64/"
datadir="D:/Apps/MySQL/data5713/"
default-character-set=utf8

innodb_data_home_dir="D:/APPS/MySQL/data5713/"
```

Nevertheless, when I run `mysqld.exe`,

```
D:\Apps\MySQL\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\bin>mysqld --verbose --console
```

I see the messages like

```
[ERROR] Can't read from messagefile 'D:\Apps\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\share\english\errmsg.sys'

Setting file 'D:\APPS\MySQL\data51\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
```

and so on.

This path is from different version of MySQL.

Where can it take it and how to force MySQL use paths I want?

**UPDATE**

If I run mysqlcheck, it prints, amongst other things, the following text:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf D:\Apps\MySQL\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\my.ini D:\Apps\MySQL\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\my.cnf D:\Apps\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini D:\Apps\MySQL\MySQL Serv
er 5.1\my.cnf
```

Where does it take these locations?

**UPDATE 2**

Running

```
d:\apps\mysql\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe --console --defaults-file="d:\apps\mysql\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\my.ini"
```

didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Change the path with \ forward slash in my.ini. Then restart the MySQL service and have a check. I also suggest you to verify that the basedir/datadir path is correct.

```
basedir="D:\Apps\MySQL\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\"
datadir="D:\Apps\MySQL\data5713\"
```